# map a hexagonal grid in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

I'm wanting to draw a figure with a hexagonal grid. The end result should look like a honeycomb. However, I'm having trouble getting my hexagons sized correctly using matplotlib.collections.RegularPolyCollection. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, or offer another solution. I imagine this has been done before, so no need for me to reinvent the wheel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections, transforms
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
import numpy as np

# Make some offsets, doing 4 polygons for simplicity here
xyo = [(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)]
# length of hexagon side
hexside = 1
# area of circle circumscribing the hexagon
circ_area = np.pi * hexside ** 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
col = collections.RegularPolyCollection(6, np.radians(90), sizes = (circ_area,),
    offsets=xyo,transOffset=ax.transData)
ax.add_collection(col, autolim=True)
colors = [colorConverter.to_rgba(c) for c in ('r','g','b','c')]
col.set_color(colors)
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I think your confusion is because the size/area specified by `sizes` is in points, rather than data coordinates.   However, an easier route for what you're doing is probably to exploit `hexbin`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whoever struggles with the same issue in 2020+, check out my [hexalattice](https://github.com/alexkaz2/hexalattice) module:
It allows to create hexagonal grids (hexagonal lattices) in 2D with fine control over spatial distribution of the hexagons, circular clop of the lattice and rotations around the central slot.

**Usage and graphical output:**

```
from hexalattice.hexalattice import *
hex_centers, _ = create_hex_grid(nx=10,
                                 ny=10,
                                 do_plot=True)
plt.show()    # import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

[image: Hexagonal grid of 10x10 hexagons]

**Installation:**

```
'>> pip install hexalattice'
```

**Advanced features**

The module allows stacking of few grids, arbitrary grid rotation around its center, advanced control over gaps between the hexagons etc.

Example:

```
hex_grid1, h_ax = create_hex_grid(nx=50,
                              ny=50,
                              rotate_deg=0,
                              min_diam=1,
                              crop_circ=20,
                              do_plot=True)
create_hex_grid(nx=50,
                ny=50,
                min_diam=1,
                rotate_deg=5,
                crop_circ=20,
                do_plot=True,
                h_ax=h_ax)
```

[image: Two round hexagonal lattices create Moire pattern when differ by small rotation]

Comment: Any easy way to get the coordinates of the vertices in some order? (now only hexagon centers can be extracted).

Comment: The hexalattice module doesn't provide info regarding the vertices, but the calculation of those is straightforward:
Assuming that the hexagon is in a 'pointy top' position, the location of the upper vertex can be obtained by adding the maximal radius to the central point.
See this great blog for more info https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/